# Как оптимально быстро выполнять существующий sql запрос с разными значениями параметра, который выходит в блок where?

Tags: sql, циклы

Есть два запроса, они выполняются из одной базы.

```
select userid, type, sum(amount) from fct_bonus
where userid=123 and date<='2016-08-01'
group by type

CREATE TABLE Tbalance (select userid, sum(case when type = 'IN' then amount when type = 'OUT' then - amount end) as balance
from fct_bonus
where date <= '2016-08-01'
group by userid)

SELECT COUNT(userid) AS CountBalance FROM Tbalance 
WHERE balance > 10000
```

Нужно запустить непрерывное выполнение по каждому запросу отдельно с изменяющейся date. Список date, по которым нужно выполнить эти запросы, содержит 300 значений и является отдельной таблицей. То есть каждый из двух запросов должен быть выполнен по 300 раз.

В задании это называют вью/агрегатом...

Comment: Оптимально быстро - не выполнять запросы 300 раз, а переписать в виде одного запроса. И тем более - не создавать временную таблицу, опять же все это спокойно решается одним запросом

Comment: _Есть два запроса_ Несколько раз пересчитывал - ну три запроса, а не два! И то, что третий не пронумерован, ровным счётом ничего не меняет... PS. distinct в первом запросе лишний.

Comment: А вот как именно будет выглядеть такой запрос - зависит от структуры БД и того, какой именно диалект SQL вы используете.

Comment: @Mike структура базы данных

create table fct_bonus (
date timestamp not null,
type varchar(10) not null,
amount numeric(19,2) not null,
userid varchar(30) not null
)
type = начисление (IN) или списание (OUT)

Использую MySql
Знакомлюсь с sql первую неделю, так что согласна, что наверное можно было проще))) Не судите строго)))

Comment: @Akina спасибо, уберу distinct!))

Comment: А что значит "запустить непрерывное выполнение" ? В SQL нет таких понятий как циклы и собственно непрерывное выполнение. Можно получить требуемый результат иными методами. А для этого надо знать что же должно получиться на выходе. В общем виде вам надо доклеить (join) в ваши запросы таблицу с датами, выполнить группировку по этой дате и у вас на выходе как раз получатся 300 строк с датами у каждой из которых готовый результат. Вот только я не понял какой же результат нужен. Операции IN/OUT отдельными строками по пользователю или количество пользователей с суммой >10k

Comment: @Mike запросы я создавала для выполнения этих задач

- Суммы накопленных и потраченных бонусов, а также баланс пользователя userid=123 на 01.08.2016
- Количество пользователей с балансом более 10 000 на 01.08.2016

Первую у меня получилось выполнить в два этапа, создав на выходе таблицу типа:

userid/type/amount
123/in/...
123/out/...

Баланс посчитала следующим этапом

select userid, sum(case when type = 'IN' then amount when type = 'OUT' then - amount end) as balance
from fct_bonus
where userid = 123 and date <= '2016-08-01'

Получила таблицу типа

userid/balance/...

Comment: @Mike в идеале это наверное можно было как-то прописать в один этап
Вторую задачу выполнила при помощи Create table и Select count
Теперь по этим двум задачам необходимо еще выполнить подстановку дат, чтобы на месте 2016-08-01 поочередно оказывались даты из списка (список отдельной таблицей)

Comment: Ну второй и третий запросы преобразуются один. `select count(1) from (запрос-который-в-create-table) X where balance>1000`

Comment: Пусть таблица с датами date_tab, тогда первый можно было бы записать как `select D.date, B.userid, B.type, sum(B.amount) from fct_bonus B join date_tab D on B.date<=D.date
where userid=123
group by D.date, B.type` второй аналогично, может чуть сложнее

Comment: @Mike, большое спасибо, очень помогло!!!!